# StickyBits NFSv4 ACL to stop user movement of folders

Tags: posix, acl, administration

Backstory: Client has a mixed environment of POSIX and NFSv4. The POSIX blows away the underlying NFSv4 ACL every-time they touch it or do anything with it. They say that users are able to take a folder and move it into another folder even though the NFSv4 ACL has the delete parameter turned off. As in a move is a delete.

The client then attempted to chmod 1755 to the folder but the files can still be moved.

The parent ACL for the file looks like this:

```
#NFSv4 ACL
#owner:root
#group:root
special:owner@:rwxc:allow
 (X)READ/LIST (X)WRITE/CREATE (X)APPEND/MKDIR (X)SYNCHRONIZE (X)READ_ACL  (X)READ_ATTR  (X)READ_NAMED  
 (-)DELETE    (X)DELETE_CHILD (X)CHOWN        (X)EXEC/SEARCH (X)WRITE_ACL (X)WRITE_ATTR (X)WRITE_NAMED

special:group@:rwx-:allow
 (X)READ/LIST (X)WRITE/CREATE (X)APPEND/MKDIR (X)SYNCHRONIZE (X)READ_ACL  (X)READ_ATTR  (X)READ_NAMED
 (-)DELETE    (X)DELETE_CHILD (-)CHOWN        (X)EXEC/SEARCH (-)WRITE_ACL (-)WRITE_ATTR (-)WRITE_NAMED

special:everyone@:rwx-:allow
 (X)READ/LIST (X)WRITE/CREATE (X)APPEND/MKDIR (X)SYNCHRONIZE (X)READ_ACL  (X)READ_ATTR  (X)READ_NAMED
 (-)DELETE    (X)DELETE_CHILD (-)CHOWN        (X)EXEC/SEARCH (-)WRITE_ACL (-)WRITE_ATTR (-)WRITE_NAMED
```

When I create a test directory inside this parent folder I get the following NFSv4 ACL:

```
#NFSv4 ACL
#owner:root
#group:root
special:owner@:rwxc:allow
 (X)READ/LIST (X)WRITE/CREATE (X)APPEND/MKDIR (X)SYNCHRONIZE (X)READ_ACL  (X)READ_ATTR  (X)READ_NAMED
 (-)DELETE    (X)DELETE_CHILD (X)CHOWN        (X)EXEC/SEARCH (X)WRITE_ACL (X)WRITE_ATTR (X)WRITE_NAMED

special:group@:r-x-:allow
 (X)READ/LIST (-)WRITE/CREATE (-)APPEND/MKDIR (X)SYNCHRONIZE (X)READ_ACL  (X)READ_ATTR  (X)READ_NAMED
 (-)DELETE    (-)DELETE_CHILD (-)CHOWN        (X)EXEC/SEARCH (-)WRITE_ACL (-)WRITE_ATTR (-)WRITE_NAMED

special:everyone@:r-x-:allow
 (X)READ/LIST (-)WRITE/CREATE (-)APPEND/MKDIR (X)SYNCHRONIZE (X)READ_ACL  (X)READ_ATTR  (X)READ_NAMED
 (-)DELETE    (-)DELETE_CHILD (-)CHOWN        (X)EXEC/SEARCH (-)WRITE_ACL (-)WRITE_ATTR (-)WRITE_NAMED
```

When i create a test file inside this new directory I get the following NFSv4 ACL:

```
#NFSv4 ACL
#owner:root
#group:root
special:owner@:rw-c:allow
 (X)READ/LIST (X)WRITE/CREATE (X)APPEND/MKDIR (X)SYNCHRONIZE (X)READ_ACL  (X)READ_ATTR  (X)READ_NAMED
 (-)DELETE    (-)DELETE_CHILD (X)CHOWN        (-)EXEC/SEARCH (X)WRITE_ACL (X)WRITE_ATTR (X)WRITE_NAMED

special:group@:r---:allow
 (X)READ/LIST (-)WRITE/CREATE (-)APPEND/MKDIR (X)SYNCHRONIZE (X)READ_ACL  (X)READ_ATTR  (X)READ_NAMED
 (-)DELETE    (-)DELETE_CHILD (-)CHOWN        (-)EXEC/SEARCH (-)WRITE_ACL (-)WRITE_ATTR (-)WRITE_NAMED

special:everyone@:r---:allow
 (X)READ/LIST (-)WRITE/CREATE (-)APPEND/MKDIR (X)SYNCHRONIZE (X)READ_ACL  (X)READ_ATTR  (X)READ_NAMED
 (-)DELETE    (-)DELETE_CHILD (-)CHOWN        (-)EXEC/SEARCH (-)WRITE_ACL (-)WRITE_ATTR (-)WRITE_NAMED
```

1. **I have found the following which I believe may help by applying a sticky bit to an NFSv4 ACL = MODE4_SVTX** How do integrate this into my existing NFSv4 ACL visually? After I figure this out I can go ahead and push it down the tree.
2. Is it the delete child element in the ACL allowing these folders to be moved into other folders?

The GOAL: Finding a way to allow sticky bits onto NFSv4 ACLs to stop people other than the owner of that file moving/deleting it.

Extra Info:

Two access mask bits govern the ability to delete a directory entry:
ACE4_DELETE on the object itself (the "target"), and
ACE4_DELETE_CHILD on the containing directory (the "parent").
​Many systems also take the "sticky bit" (MODE4_SVTX) on a directory
to allow unlink only to a user that owns either the target or the
parent; on some such systems the decision also depends on whether the
target is writable.​

Servers SHOULD allow unlink if either ACE4_DELETE is permitted on the
target, or ACE4_DELETE_CHILD is permitted on the parent. (Note that
this is true even if the parent or target explicitly denies one of
these permissions.)

If the ACLs in question neither explicitly ALLOW nor DENY either of
the above, and if MODE4_SVTX is not set on the parent, then the
server SHOULD allow the removal if and only if ACE4_ADD_FILE is
permitted. In the case where MODE4_SVTX is set, the server may also
require the remover to own either the parent or the target, or may
require the target to be writable.

This allows servers to support something close to traditional UNIXlike
semantics, with ACE4_ADD_FILE taking the place of the write bit.